# Can't vMotion specific VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmotion

I have a VM (2008 R2, running SQL) that sits on a dedicated VLAN 70 that sits behind my TMG firewall. There is also a small CentOS web server that sits in the same DMZ, usually on the same ESXi box.

When I do a vMotion of the SQL box there is no network response.

When I do a vMotion for the web server everything works exactly as expected. I am in the process of creating a clone so I can experiment with this behavior but I am at a loss as to why this behavior is occurring or how to debug.

Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something odd going on with the VMware Tools installation on that system. Why that would impact a vMotion is beyond me.

There were several VSS errors thrown by the client OS and several network related errors thrown by the ESXi host specific to this VM.

EDIT - 
The network errors requested are:

```
<ESX server> vmkernel: 37:02:57:06.600 cpu10:4106)WARNING: E1000: vm 15885: 8608: Failed to queue blocking map of PA 0x13f45800a and length 1522 bytes.
```

Comment: The network errors are particularly interesting - can you provide those messages?  Maybe an issue with the adapter type in use?

Answer (score 2):

The times I've run into this, it ended up being that the VM's VLAN wasn't actually presented to the ESX host! It was happily using VLAN 70, but the switch wasn't set to accept VLAN 70 from those switch-ports.

Comment: I wish it was that simple.. The web server vmotions correctly using the exact same network settings.